# Can't get facebook user's profile picture without access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

I'm getting user's profile picture in this way:  https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture and everything was fine until today. Today i lunched my app and i started getting default profile pictures instead of real one.

It seems that now i need access token.

**not working**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture
```

**working**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

**Question**

What happened? I haven't changed anything in the code or configuration of the fb app and yesterday everything was working like a charm.

Important to know: My app is in development mode

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture#requirements-change lists an upcoming change, but that is supposed to go live on Oct 24. Plus I am guessing your user-id is probably an app-scoped one to begin with?

Comment: Yes, my user id is app-scoped. I am not sure if i understood it correctly. If i go with Live mode will i receive real profile picture from tokenless request?

Comment: From my research, user ids fall in the range [(id < 2200000000 || (id >= 100000000000000 && id <= 100099999989999)](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-js-sdk/blob/deprecated/src/xfbml/helper.js#L37). App scoped user ids will fall outside of this range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your platform, you can get the temporary access token

**Android**

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
}
```

**iOS**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSString *accessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
}
```

**Javascript**

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } 
} );
```

A much more detailed code snippet and explanation can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

After you get the accessToken, You can then get the user's Facebook profile picture from the Graph API using `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` , just as you said.

Comment: Hey @Adeolaex, does the app need to be "live" or "verified" in order to get a valid access token?

Comment: Hey there @Alex. No, one can still use most if not all the API's on apps that are "in development". So to answer your question, **the app doesn't need to be "live"** to get the access token.

Comment: I have tested to append the "ACESS_TOKEN" to the request but I get the following message: "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1234567' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"

Comment: I might have made a mistake with my previous comment. On the Facebook App dashboard , please navigate to the Roles section over at the left hand corner and make sure an Administrator is set up. If an app is not "live", one will be limited to make API calls with such accounts. I believe Admin, Dev and Tester accounts. Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I also was getting the default grey facebook profile picture working in Android Studio on Java. I have the following facebook-login version 8.2.0 dependency in Gradle:
`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:8.2.0'`.

I code in Android Studio on Java. The solution that worked for me was to fetch the profile picture when signed in using this line:

```
Uri photoUrl = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(200, 200);
```

where `Profile` is from `import com.facebook.Profile`.